# Can I cache website in chrome so it show even if it becomes offline?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I want to have chrome in kiosk mode to show my website. The problem is though, the website is offline around 10% of the time.

I created the .bat script that pings the website and shows another one if it fails to ping.

The problem is the website changes once per week and I have this script on 60 kiosks, so updating automatically would be problematic.

What would be the easiest way to update those kiosks having only chrome and windows batch? I cannot install git, python etc on them.

Comment: Isn't it better you fix the problem with the site availability  first?

Comment: @B001ᛦ I can't - it's about my client server management. They want kiosks to work even when they tinker with servers

Comment: So what is stopping you from enabling offline mode in chrome?

Comment: @Squashman nothing is stopping me, I'm asking the question to find solution, I will check offline mode now, as I never heard about it.

Comment: you can have a look at [this page](https://www.maketecheasier.com/offline-mode-google-chrome/)

Comment: @TutuKaeen basically paste the following text into your chrome browser `chrome://flags` then search for _"Show Saved Copy Button"_ and click on the `default` dropdown on the right, then select `Primary`. Also search for _"Offline Auto-Reload Mode"_ and set it to `enable`.